# Github project clone and push on temporary machine

Tags: windows, git, macos, github

I know github has changed the code push strategy and made it a token based one, even though I haven't tried it yet, but is there a way to push the code to github by using username/password as I am using a temporary laptop and don't want to save any personal details.

I am getting the below error:

remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.

Comment: For `git push` purposes, a PAT *is* a password: just make one and use it "as if" it were a password and you're fine. The real difference between the PAT and your actual password is that if your PAT is compromised, you use your real password to log in and store a new PAT and nobody knows your password.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to push the code to github by using username/password as I am using a temporary laptop and don't want to save any personal details.

You can [generate a PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) just for that temporary laptop

Or you can generate an SSH key on that temporary laptop, that you will use only there, with an SSH URL.

In both instances, you can revoke (the PAT or the public registered SSH key) later on, when you no longer use that temporary laptop.